# How to enable javascript after page loading to change input attribute to disabled depends on other input value that load from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to write a Javascript code that can disabled my text input after I checked the checkbox. However I also want to run the Javascript code after the page load.

I have tried some Javascript and succeed. The text input will be disabled if I check the textbox. But, I will read from my database whether to check or uncheck the checkbox, the problem here is If the checkbox is checked because of the database. The text input will not be disabled according to the javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#checker').on('load', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){

        $('#yourText').prop('disabled', true);


    }else{


        $('#yourText').prop('disabled', false);


    }    
});
</script>
```

I expect if the checkbox is checked like default or from database, the text input will be disabled.

Comment: Just make sure everything is occurring in the correct sequence.  Is the value from db populated via ajax call or server-side in page render?  The answer to this question will determine your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if(document.getElementById('checker').checked == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = false;
    }
});
```

or you can write it in php

```
    <?php
        if([databaseField] == "YES")
        {
            $checker = "disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $checker = "";
        } 
    ?>

    <input type="text" name="yourText" id="yourText" $checker>
```